# Stringing KnockOut conditionals together

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In the aspx of my page I have the following Knockout conditional:

```
<tbody id="resultsTable" data-bind="foreach: get_contacts()">
  <!-- ko if: get_xPos() == 0 -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span data-bind="text: get_lname()">
      </span>
      , 
      <span data-bind="text:get_fname()">
      </span>

      <br />
      <span data-bind="text: get_email()">
      </span>
      <br />
      <span data-bind="text: get_phone()">
      </span>
      <br />
      <span data-bind="text: get_office()">
      </span>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <!-- /ko -->

</tbody>
```

This **works** by itself. If I add another Knockout conditional immediately after the first (directly before the `</tbody>`), Knockout throws an error `Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko ifnot: get_xPos() == 0`:

```
  <!-- ko ifnot: get_xPos() == 0 -->
  <td>
    <span data-bind="text: get_lname()">
    </span>
    , 
    <span data-bind="text:get_fname()">
    </span>

    <br />

    <span data-bind="text: get_email()">
    </span>
    <br />
    <span data-bind="text: get_phone()">
    </span>
    <br />
    <span data-bind="text: get_office()">
    </span>
  </td>
  <!-- /ko -->
```

The intention here is to conditionally create a new row. If my element has an xPosition of 0, then I make a new row and cell. Otherwise I just create a new cell in my table.

Can anyone point out what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You trying to create `<td>` in `<tbody>` without `<tr>` in second condition.

Comment: @Ivan.Srb Ah, yeah I see that now. Thanks. Do you get what I'm trying to do though? Any ideas?

Comment: The other question is *why* are you using those ifs like that in the first place - seems awfully redundant to me.

Comment: @Tomalak Because I want to create a new row on every 5th contact.

Comment: So you want to create table with 5 cells in each row?

Comment: @tnw That's the essential bit of information. *That* should have been your question. You don't really want what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Tomalak I understand your point, I figured that general idea (which is to conditionally create a new row using a knockout if/else) was made clear in the 2nd to last paragraph.

Comment: @Tomalak So that being cleared up, any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want *5 cells per row* or (like your code sample suggests) *5 contacts per cell*, once cell per row?

Comment: Sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/nSMbc/3/ for 5 cells per row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

> - So you want to create table with 5 cells in each row?
> - Right.

Reflect that circumstance in your view model. That's what it's for. The view should not do this.
Computed observables are the way to solve this. In your view model add:

```
self.contactRows = ko.computed(function () {
    var rows = [],
        i, 
        contacts = self.get_contacts();

    for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i += 5) {
        rows.push( contacts.slice(i, i + 5) );
    }

    return rows;
});
```

and in your view use it:

```
<tbody id="resultsTable" data-bind="foreach: contactRows">
  <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <td>
      <span data-bind="text: get_lname()"></span>, 
      <span data-bind="text: get_fname()"></span><br />
      <span data-bind="text: get_email()"></span><br />
      <span data-bind="text: get_phone()"></span><br />
      <span data-bind="text: get_office()"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Think if you can find a nicer markup for what you are trying to to.

---

Maybe that's a better approach:

Semantically you are trying to display a (nested) list. Using `ul` / `li` with appropriate CSS would result in more meaningful markup than using a `table`. And you wouldn't have to fill in meaningless empty cells just to make the table look right.

You could even drop the idea of nesting altogether and make a single list that you style to allow a maximum of 5 "contact" list items per row (fixed dimension items floated left in a container that's 5 times wider than a single item).

That way you could use one simple `foreach` binding in your view and you'd not need a computed observable at all. Displaying 6 or 4 items per row would amount to one trivial CSS change.

Comment: Very good explanation, I understand. I don't actually have one cell per row, what I'm trying to do is make contact cards for an employee directory. Each contact card would have a user's info displayed (in a cell) and there would be 5 contact cards in a row. This worked though, thank you.

Comment: Think about the `<ul>` approach, too.

Comment: I will, that sounds like a much better approach than pushing a table beyond what it's really supposed to do.

Comment: Of course this will only work if all your items can fit into the same fixed size. For contact cards this might be an option though.

Comment: So I did end up scrapping the whole table format as well as the ul/li. Making a fixed width container for a card and floating card divs left did the trick much better than the table ever did. Thank you so much for your advisement!

Comment: Good to hear! :) Semantically ul/li is still the way to go. The HTML structure is no different than using div/div, but the meaning is transported better. And it works right when styles are disabled.

Comment: Yeah, this way I don't even have to worry about computing this stuff... it all floats into place dynamically. Dynamic is always better